# Moving the focus of Edittext horizontally in list adapter android

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

Showing EditText in ListView adapter issue coming into focus:

[image]

Each List item has three `EditText`. I want to change the focus horizontally.

I am successfully able to move focus from the first to the third `EditText` using this code.

The issue is coming when I press softkeyboard next. I want to move the focus to the next list row, first `EditText`. However, when I use this code given below the focus switches to the same list, first `EditText`

```
holder.edtStock.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            if(holder.edtStock.hasFocus())
                holder.edtOrderStock.requestFocus();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

holder.edtOrderStock.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            if(holder.edtOrderStock.hasFocus())
                holder.edtStock.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

I want to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your EditText using `android:nextFocusForward="@+id/edtNumeroInterior"` and `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

if you want to change to down using `nextFocusDown`